# Shnayim mikrah v'echad targum - why twice?

Tags: halacha, number, pentateuch-chumash

There is a mitzvah to read the parsha of the week in preparation for every Shabbat - the Hebrew of each verse twice, and a translation or commentary of that verse once. I understand that the translation/commentary is necessary to increase (or simply achieve) understanding of the verse, but why do we need to repeat the verse?

Comment: related (duplicate?) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8202

Comment: @Fred That looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Fred Might be a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DoubleAA and Daniel: Yeah, the other question includes this one, and the answers there seem to answer this.

Comment: Whoops! Looks like a duplicate question that has already been well-answered. Sorry.

Comment: @MichaelSandler, nothing to be sorry about. Now we have a different expression of the question, so people googling for this question are more likely to find it.

Answer (score 0):

My son asked me this question.
I told him I don't know but my guess is that VeSheenantam which refers to Torah has a root that would perhaps suggest Shnayim - Two.