# Reading the Parsha when not with a minyan on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, torah-reading, tzibur-community, parsha-torah-portion

If one has gone away for shabbat, and does not have access to a synagogue or minyan, to what extent is he obligated in reading from that weeks' Torah portion? Is he not obligated at all? Should he read the parsha from a chumash (in full or in part)? Or a different solution?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/what-is-the-reason-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sefer Ishei Yisrael pg 423, the author cites the [Ketzos Hashulchan siman 25:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7720&pgnum=155) that if one prayed alone then one should read the parsha from a chumash. He then cites in the next halacha (from Mishna Brurah 143:9, and Orach Neman seif 7) that in a place (yishuv) where there is no kosher sefer Torah then one person from the minyan should read from a Chumash standing and should read the haftorah, but no brachas should be said. Chatzi kaddish is said after this type of reading.