# Has anyone seen or heard of a heter not to read shnayim mikrah ve'echad targum?

Tags: halacha, parsha-torah-portion, leniencies

The given psak by all poskim that I know of seems to be that shnayim mikrah is a total obligation. Is there any source that says otherwise?

Comment: Are you looking for an opinion of a living Rabbi? A Rishon? A Tanna?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8207/440

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan (ad loc, 2) posits that this is a takkana from Moshe Rabbeinu! See Shu”t Maharsham (vol.1, 213 s.v. ulam) who states that although it is not technically a “chiyuv gamur” like reading the Torah, it has since been equated to the status of “chiyuv”).
http://ohr.edu/5029#_edn2

Answer (score 8):

The following is from ספר ראב׳׳ן, a contemporary of Rabbenu Tam and his brothers the Rashbam and the Rivam:

> **ראב"ן שאלות ותשובות (בתחילת הספר) סימן פח** לעולם ישלים אדם פרשיותיו עם הציבור ב' מקרא ואחד תרגום. נ"ל דביחיד הדר בכרך מיירי שאין לו עשרה לקרות בתורה, שצריך לכוין השעה שקורין הציבור בפרשה בבהכ"נ ויקרא גם הוא ביחיד שנים מקרא כנגד שנים הקורין בב"ה ואחד תרגום כנגד המתרגם בב"ה, שכן היה מנהגם כדתנן [מגילה כ"ג ב] הקורא בתורה לא יפחות לקרות פחות מג' פסוקים ולא יקרא למתרגם יותר מפסוק אחד, דאם כמו שפירשו רבותיי דבקריאת הפרשה בבוקר בשבת מיירי כמו שאנו רגילין, לימא לעולם יקרא אדם הפרשה בשבת שנים מקרא וכו', עם הציבור למה לי, אלא ודאי עם הציבור ממש כדפרישית, ועוד שנים מקרא וכו' למה לי הלא ישמעו בב"ה ויצאו ידי חובתן. ואעפ"כ מנהגינו מנהג גמור, דזימנין דלא מצי מכוין דעתיה בב"ה לכל הפרשה ויצא בקריאה שקרא כבר.

Translation:

> It appears to me the the statement "one should always finish his פרשה **with the community** with the translation'' refers only to a lone person in an outlying town [where there will be no Torah or no minyan-Moses], as he needs to discern the time which the community will read it together and read it by himself at the same time, as that is how they read at that time, as is evident in Masechet Megillah. For if it to be explained as my teachers have explained it that it refers to the reading in the synagogue in the morning as we do, why does [the talmud] say ''with the community''? It should say ''finish the פרשה with the translation''. But it definitely means as I said, literally with the community. Furthermore, what is the point? They will fulfill their obligation when they hear the reading in the synagogue. Even so, our practice is *the* practice, as sometimes he will lose concentration in the synagogue and fulfills his obligation with his previous reading. [my translation]

I have never heard this opinion brought down להלכה.